# Get values from CSV Selenium

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I am trying to write a selenium script to post ad on craiglist. I have the selenium script as following in which the post values are directly passed.

```
var driver = test.openBrowser();
var selenium = driver.getSelenium();

var timeout = 30000;
selenium.setTimeout(timeout);

var tx = test.beginTransaction();

var step = test.beginStep("Step 1");
selenium.open("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=5I1SUur9EsTirAed8oCgBA");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 2");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.type("id=gbqfq", "chennai craiglist");
selenium.keyPress("id=gbqfq", "\13");
selenium.click("link=craigslist: chennai (madras) classifieds for jobs, apartments ...");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 3");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 4");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.click("link=admin / office");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 5");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.doubleClick("id=ef");
selenium.click("link=post");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 6");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.click("name=id");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 7");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.click("name=go");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 8");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.click("xpath=//section[@class='body']/form/blockquote/label[2]/input");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 9");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.type("id=PostingTitle", "Post title ");
selenium.type("id=GeographicArea");
selenium.type("id=GeographicArea", "Post location");
selenium.type("id=PostingBody", "Post description");
selenium.type("id=FromEMail", "replyto@gmail.com");
selenium.type("id=ConfirmEMail", "replyto@gmail.com");
selenium.type("id=compensation", "DOE");
selenium.click("name=go");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 10");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
selenium.click("name=file");
selenium.click("name=go");
selenium.click("xpath=//section[@class='body']//button[.='done with images']");
test.endStep();

test.beginStep("Step 11");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad(60000);
test.endStep();

test.endTransaction();
```

I trying the script to be in such a way that these values are stored in a CSV file and values should be read from that. I tried using python along with it. But I failed.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. From the [Craiglist Terms of Use](https://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use): "It is expressly prohibited to post content to craigslist using any automated means. Users must post all content personally and manually through all steps of the posting process."

Comment: Yes. I understand. TOSs apart.

Comment: Try this instead: https://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface

Comment: Thats looks cool. But can I automate that?